# cocoon link_to_add_association adds empty association fields rails 4 erb

Tags: activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-4.1, cocoon-gem

Am using cocoon gem (1.2.6) in my rails 4.1 + activeadmin application. the link_to_add_association added empty fields with **new** attached in the ERB form. please the refer the input id below

```
<input id="lease_information_lease_units_attributes_new_lease_units_property_name" type="text" name="lease_information[lease_units_attributes][new_lease_units][property_name]">
```

when i click the link_to_add_association creates fields with id.

```
<input id="lease_information_lease_units_attributes_1420800589434_property_name" type="text" name="lease_information[lease_units_attributes][1420800589434][property_name]">
```

my lease_informations/_lease_units.html.erb form :

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :cocoon %>

<div id='lease_units'>
  <%= f.semantic_fields_for :lease_units do |lease_unit| %>
    <%= render 'lease_unit_fields', f: lease_unit %>
  <% end %>  
  <div class='links'>
    <%= link_to_add_association image_tag("icon-new.png", height: '18', width: '18'), f, :lease_units, title: "Add Unit" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

partial _lease_unit_fields.html.erb :

```
<div class='nested-fields'>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr >
        <td class="col col-unit_type">
          <%= f.text_field :unit_type %>
        </td>
        <td class="col col-unit">
          <%= f.text_field :unit %>
        </td>
        <td class="col col-action">
          <%= link_to_remove_association image_tag("icon-remove.png", height: '18', width: '18'), f, title: "Remove Unit" %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

my admin/lease_information.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register LeaseInformation do
  menu false
  controller do
    def new
      @page_title="Data Entry Form"
      @lease_information = LeaseInformation.new
      # @lease_information.lease_units.build
    end
  end
  form do |f|
    tabs do
      tab 'Units' do
        table_for resource.lease_units do
         column :unit_type
         column :unit
        end
        render "lease_units", f: f  # rendering the partial here
      end
    f.actions do
      f.action :submit, label: "Submit"
      f.cancel_link(admin_jobs_path)
    end
  end
end
```

because of this the nested fields are not getting saved in db. can any one please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: can you please post your main form where you are adding lease_units partial

Comment: added the main form in the post. please refer

Comment: Please move following line in `admin/lease_information.rb` file 
i think this will resolve your problem.
`
<td class="col col-action">
  <%= link_to_remove_association image_tag("icon-remove.png", height: '18', width: '18'), f, title: "Remove Unit" %>
</td>
`

Comment: @ManiDavid did you get solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think moving following code from `lease_informations/_lease_units.html.erb` to `admin/lease_information.rb` file will resolve your problem.

```
<div class='links'>
  <%= link_to_add_association image_tag("icon-new.png", height: '18', width: '18'), f, :lease_units, title: "Add Unit" %>
</div>
```

Please revert back if you get any error or need any help.

Comment: tried , but the fields are coming with **new** attached, any other solution pls.
`admin/lease_information.rb
 form do |f|
    tabs do
      tab 'Units' do 
         f.semantic_fields_for :lease_units do |lease_unit|
          # render "lease_units", f: f
          render 'lease_unit_fields', f: lease_unit
         end
         link_to_add_association image_tag("icon-new.png", height: '18', width: '18'), f, :lease_units, title: "Add Unit"
end
end
end`

Answer (score 0):

If the saving does not work, it sounds like you are missing the required `accepts_nested_attributes_for :lease_units` in your parent model.

The large number instead of new is correct behaviour, each new child has to be distinct, we cannot call each new child new, so we choose a large, unique and unexisting number so rails will know it is a new child.

Comment: app/models/lease_information.rb
class LeaseInformation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :lease_units
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :lease_units, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end. accepts_nested_attributes already present in model. yes the large number is correct but initially fields with new are present wich stops the value saving in db.

Comment: What error are you seeing? Is some validation failing? The `new` is akward, not necessarily wrong. In your code the `lease_units.build` is commented out, so where is the new element generated?